# Problems with relative path while including database constants

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into problems when I require a php file that contains my constants if I use a relative path. When I change it to an absolute path, it works well but I don't want to deploy it into production while it's in this state. The errors I get are:

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\photoGallery\includes\database.php on line 10

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\photoGallery\includes\database.php on line 10

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\photoGallery\includes\database.php on line 10

There are three files:
database.php which requires config.php -> They both reside in the same directory called 'includes'

and there's index.php which resides a directory up one level called 'public'

Code in config.php

```
// Database Constants
 defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
 defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "ugallery");
 defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "ugallerypword");
 defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
```

Code in database.php

```
require_once("config.php");
class MySQLDatabase {
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->open_connection();
    }
    public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: ".mysql_error());
        } else{
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
            if(!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: ".mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    public function close_connection() {
        if(isset($this->connection)) {
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }
    public function query($sql) {
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    private function confirm_query($result) {
        if(!$result) {
            die("Database query failed: ".mysql_error());
        }
    }

    public function mysql_prep( $value ) {
        $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
        $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
        if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
            // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
            if( $magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
        } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
            // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
            if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
            // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
        }
        return $value;
    }

}
$database = new MySQLDatabase();
```

Code in index.php

```
<?php require_once("../includes/database.php"); ?>
<?php
    if(isset($database)) { echo "true";} else { echo "false";} 
    echo "<hr />";
    echo $database->mysql_prep("It's working");
?>
```

If I change the require_once in database.php to

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/photoGallery/includes/config.php");
```

Then everything works as it should.

Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: just read about the difference between require_once and require. which is kind of obvious

Comment: Is your config.php file and your database file in the same directory?

Comment: @Marinus yes they are in the same directory

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan yes the difference is obvious but that has no bearing whatsoever.

Comment: sorry and the index.php page is it under /photoGallery folder?

Comment: @Marinus the index is inside a folder called /public which resides inside the /photoGallery folder which is the main folder for the project. The config.php and database.php are in the same folder called /includes. The /includes directory and /public directory are on the same level inside the /photoGallery

Comment: @Marinus thanks for the replies. Solved it; see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using **DIR** in php5.3 and above

In the database.php file

```
require_once(__DIR__."/config.php");
```